# Piecewise Functions difficulty

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions, word-problem

I am new here. I need a bit of help. Not the best at math.

Johnny jumps from a plane at $3000$ feet in the sky. After $35$ seconds, he deploys a parachute. $h =$ height. $t =$ # of seconds after jumping. 
$$h(t) = 
\begin{cases}
-51.5t + 3000 &  \text{if $0 \leq t \leq 35$}\\
-8.9t + 1509 &  \text{if $t > 35$}
\end{cases}
$$
When does Johnny hit the ground?

I thought a process of $3000 = -8.9t + 1509$ would work but when I solved for $t$, my results were $-167.53$.

I like to picture this on an $x,y$ plane and I do not understand how a negative number could be incorporated in this context. Or perhaps my answer is just wrong altogether?

Also for clarification, what in this sense would be an example of functional notation?

I assume the explanation would provide the interval notation. I think it would be $(-167.53, 3000)$?

Comment: The plane is at height 3000 (notice that he jumps at $t=0$ and $h(0)=3000$). So he hits the ground when $h(t)=0$.

Comment: If you're getting a time, t, then your answer should be positive. Just set up two equations. Set the first piece of the function equal to zero. Then do the same for the second piece. Which answer does it have to be?

Comment: He lands at 169.55 seconds?!

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

He jumps at $0$, so the function must be set to $0$. 
\begin{align*}
0 & = -8.9t + 1509\\
8.9t & = 1509\\
t &= 169.55
\end{align*}
He lands a little over $2$ minutes.

Comment: Your calculations are correct.  Since there are $60~\text{s}$ in a minute, $169.55~\text{s}$ is equivalent to $2~\text{min}~49.55~\text{s}$, which is nearly three minutes.